# Design? Or something else

Tags: design, modeling, research

When we develop a new technical device (after creating its general concept), we want to implement it. But before we implement it, we must design it. And for this we go through some stages (the list is purely subjective and may change):

1. determination of environmental conditions and working space of the device;
2. choice of architecture;
3. assessment of what research is needed for each component of the architecture: selection of an existing device, development of a new one (engineering + mathematics);
4. selection or development of methods for assessing kinematic, dynamic, weight and size indicators, as well as obtaining results;
5. analysis of calculation results, optimization of device parameters based on the developed methods;
6. development of mathematical models, choice of its structure, assessment of adequacy;
7. development of a physical sample of the device, experiments, etc.

What word or phrase summarizes the above points? Design? Or something else ...

Comment: 7 : prototyping

Comment: I'd call all seven steps a design process.

Comment: Sometimes it is difficult to clearly separate design from development. But the design definitely comes a little earlier than the development. The difficulty is caused by a rather broad meaning of the word "development", in which all the steps described in the question can be invested, including the choice of architecture, the development of design methods, etc. That is why "development" is perceived as a single package, which, in theory, includes design as well.

Comment: is that a school question?

Comment: Sometimes the "design process" doesn't methodically flow as indicated, with one step being completed prior to commencing the next step. Occasionally there is a feedback loop where a design has been completed & development then occurs, however, during the development phase a realization occurs that the design was not sufficient & needs to changed. Development ceases & a redesign or design adjustment occurs before development starts again. This can have several iterations.